Elasticity theory: homogeneous deformations of a perfect lattice
I want to understand how the macroscopic (linear) elasticity theory emerges from the microscopic properties of matter. My question is about the model of the "perfect lattice", which is used in several classical books, e.g. [1], [2], [3]. This model has a weird property, which I don't understand why it is postulated.
First of all, in the (linear) macroscopic elasticity theory, we have a body $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ and a bijective deformation-function $\phi: B\rightarrow \phi(B)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, which has the form $\phi(x)=x+u(x)$, where $u(x)$ is small. Elasticity-theory establishes a connection between strain and stress. One approach to do this is to use a microscopic model for the body $B$. A standard one is that $B$ is (a finite part of) a perfect lattice.
Definition (Perfect Lattice): Let $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a base of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The points
$$x(\ell)= \ell_1 v_1 + \ell_2 v_2+\ell_3 v_3$$
where $\ell=(\ell_1 ,\ell_2, \ell_3) \in\mathbb{Z}^3$ form a lattice. If we had one particle at each point of the lattice, the model would be called "simple lattice". Our model (the "perfect lattice") is slightly more complicated. Here, each cell of the lattice will contain $s$ different particles. Formally, we have $s$ points $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_s \in \mathbb{R}^3$ that lie inside the base-cell, i.e., the parallelepiped defined by the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$. These will be the positions of the particles at the base-cell. For the rest of the cells, we just copy this configuration, i.e., for the cell $\ell=(\ell_1 ,\ell_2, \ell_3) $ with origin $x(\ell)$, the positions of the particles there are $$x(\ell)+a_1,\dots,x(\ell)+a_s$$ This is illustrated (in two dimensions) by the figure below (where $s=2$):

So far so good. Now, books [1], [2] do the following strange (for me) thing. In order to establish the connection between stress and strain, they consider "homogeneous" deformations (defined below) of the perfect lattice. Notice that these deformations are not linear!
Definition (homogeneous deformation): Given a perfect lattice, a homogeneous deformation is parametrized via a small matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ and $s$ vectors $\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_s \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ which have small length, compared to the linear dimensions of the lattice cells. The deformation is
$$x(\ell)+a_i \mapsto (I+A)(x(\ell)+a_i)+\epsilon_i$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. In other words, the deformation is linear plus an arbitrary perturbation for each particle-type. Note that for each particle-type, the perturbation $\epsilon_i$ is the same amongst the cells.
This deformation is strange to me. The reason is that in elasticity-theory, to connect stress and strain, we work with linear deformations, since the deformation map $\phi$ is locally linear.
Why would we want to include these extra perturbations $\epsilon_i$?

A.E.H Love, A treatise on the mathematical theory of elasticity.
Born, Huang, Dynamical theory of crystal lattices.
Askar, Lattice dynamical foundations of continuum theories : elasticity, piezoelectricity, viscoelasticity, plasticity.


What equations are you referring to? I'm looking at displacement relations given in Love's §1.6, Born's Eq. (11.1), and Askar's Eq. (4.3) and don't see the additional term you're describing.

Thank you for taking the time! For Born, look at (11.2): the u_a(k) are the extra perturbations. The u_{a b} are the entries of matrix A. For Love (4th edition), you can see Note B, p.623 where he says "so far as the geometry of the system is concerned, \delta_a, \delta_b, \delta_c are unrestricted". Don't look at Askar, he doesn't work with any transformation; just arbitrary displacements of lattice points (but I don't think he is fully rigorous). Overall, Born's book is the easiest place to see the setting.

If you would first do the elastic deformation in a purely linear way, then the particles end up at (clearly defined) new positions, but in the new situation those may not be te lowst energy positions any more. It seems that the $\epsilon_i$ just serve to describe what changes those particles will prefer. Of course that is not defined any more by the linear deformation, it must involve the forces involved in the specific case under consideration.
